# How to break out of an IAsyncEnumerable when iterating?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

C# 8 adds support for asynchronuous iterator blocks, so you can await things and return an `IAsyncEnumarator` instead of an `IEnumerable`:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> EnumerateAsync() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield return i;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

With a **non-blocking** consuming code that looks like this:

```
await foreach (var item in EnumerateAsync()) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This will result in my code running for about 10 seconds. However, sometimes I want to break out of the `await foreach` before all elements are consumed. With an `break`however, we would need to wait until the current awaited `Task.Delay` has finished. **How can we break immediately out of that loop without waiting for any dangling async tasks?**

Comment: Are you saying that `yield break;` doesn't work inside an async enumeration?

Comment: `yield break` will work as expected, but you wouldn't be able to break while `Task.Delay` is awaited.

Comment: How to cancel any cancellable operation, including Task.Delay, isn't related to `IAsyncEnumerable`. It's not a dangling task, the same way `httpClient.GetStringAsync` isn't a dangling task

Comment: When I exit the `foreach` with a `break` on the consumer side, no awaited tasks would be cancelled by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of a `CancellationToken` is the solution since that is the only thing that can cancel the `Task.Delay` in your code. The way we get it inside your `IAsyncEnumerable` is to pass it as a parameter when creating it, so let's do that:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> EnumerateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield return i;
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

With the consuming side of:

```
// In this example the cancellation token will be caneled after 2.5 seconds
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
await foreach (var item in EnumerateAsync(cts.Token)) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Sure, this will cancel the enumeration after 3 elements were returned, but will end in an `TaskCanceledException` thrown out of `Task.Delay`. To gracefully exit the `await foreach` we have to catch it and break on the producing side:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> EnumerateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield return i;
        try {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        } catch (TaskCanceledException) {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Note

As of now this is still in preview and is subject to possible change. If you are interested in this topic you can [watch a discussion of the C# language team](https://youtu.be/XgC0oV29OqM?t=5900) about `CancellationToken` in an `IAsyncEnumeration`.

Comment: I just want to add that preview2 of VS2019 and Core 3 will have some better support for `CancellationToken`. We will provide a `.WithCancellationToken()` extension method. 
See LDM meeting notes: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-11-28.md#cancellation-of-async-streams

Comment: The Visual Studio 2019 issues a warning if you don't decorate the `CancellationToken` argument with a [`EnumeratorCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.enumeratorcancellationattribute) attribute. Also suppressing the `TaskCanceledException` in the producer side seems like a non-standard behavior. I think that this exception is conveying the information about whether a cancellation occurred or not, so it should be propagated to the caller.